# Monotouch dialog DateElement returning wrong date

Tags: dialog, xamarin.ios

I have a very strange problem with a Monotouch.Dialog DateElement. To explain what I'm doing:
I have some weight entries for dates stored in a DB. all entries are shown in a TableView.
if I click "add" i go to a DialogViewController with a DateElement and a counterelement - everything works fine.

If I select a row in the tableView i go to the same DialogViewController and i can edit the entry.
If i edit the weight (counterelement) everything is ok but if I edit the date (DateElement) i get a wrong date back.

when editing a weight entry i instanciate the DateElement like this:
dateElement = new DateElement ("Dato",weightObject.Date);

when the save button is clicked I take the new value from "dateElement.DateValue.Date" and this is where things goes wrong. I ALWAYS get a date back that is 1 day less than what I selected.

I know it sounds strange.... but I have tried tracing my way through this and can't find any bug in my code. Anyone else seen something like this?

(if I click the date and go back again without changing it then there is no problem - the problem is only there when i edit the date)

/Nicolaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the "bug".

I'm only interested in the date - not the hours, so when i save the date I take the value like this from the dateelement:
"dateElement.DateValue.Date"

Later, when I want to edit the date I assign for ex "2012-03-18 00:00:00" to the date element. 
When i get that value back it have been converted from CET to UTC somehow which means that i get the previous date :-(

So I guess i have to convert back to local time

Comment: Hi @NicolajB, I have the same issue, do you know how to convert again to local time because Im selectin for example "Jan 24,2013" and when I debug the DateValue.Date is Jan 25, 2013. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Converting back to Local time would be done with:
dateElement.DateValue.ToLocalTime()